# In Visual Studio Code "PROBLEMS" window, how to show errors in the order generated by the compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

In our Cpp project, compilation (sometimes) generate errors.

It is generally accepted that those errors are to be addressed in the order they are emitted by the compiler (because of Cpp notoriously hard parsing, solving the first error might change the interpretation of the program, even tokens happening before the error).

Yet, it seems that, in our vanilla installation of VSCode, the **PROBLEMS** window is currently showing the error grouped by file, and within each file, the errors are sorted by ascending position in the file.

How to change this behaviour so the **PROBLEMS** window show the error in the order they are emitted **(edit) within each compilation unit**?

Comment: Since each file is compiled independently of the others, the ordering of files isn't very important. Just pick one.

Comment: @molbdnilo I meant the order of errors within a file. Cpp development usually imply to address errors within each compilation unit in the order they are emitted by the compiler.

Comment: But you say " in our vanilla installation [...] within each file, the errors are sorted by ascending position in the file."

Comment: @molbdnilo Exactly, within each file, the errors are sorted by their ascending position when viewed in **PROBLEMS** window. This ordering by position is not necessarily the order in which the errors were emitted by the compiler, which is the problem here.

Comment: And comming to think of it, even the inter-files order is important. Since compilation units are oftentimes comprised of several files (usually, headers), the relative order of errors between files is still relevant for a given CU.

Comment: The compiler parser and the editor parser are independent.  Separate compilation dictates that they will be compiled in the order they appear in the makefile or whatever build system you are using.  For the order to be the same the editor would have to parse your build system too.  I imagine that the ordering is largely independent.  Perhaps there is some way you could change the build order to match the editor order, but it seems remarkably unnecessary.

Comment: The compilation order is not critical to the error parsing - an error in a common header may cause errors in multiple translation units, but it does not matter which you address first.  Fixing the error in the header will effect all including modules.  Your justification for wanting this is flawed.  Personally I largely ignore the editor/IDE generated messages, and perform a build in any case.  Often the diagnostics are more specific and easier to locate.

Comment: Surely the point of the editor parser is that you do not build up so many errors between builds that this becomes an issue?

Comment: The simplest answer is: don't use the Problems or Errors window, use the compiler output.  Not only does Problems/Errors mess up the order, it strips out contextual information (for example, when the error is "ambiguous function call", most compilers spit out a list of the candidates which were equally good matches... but as those candidates are not "errors", they don't appear in the Problems/Errors window).  This contextual information varies from quite helpful all the way up to completely essential to finding and fixing errors.

Comment: In some IDEs, the parser adds hyperlinks in the compiler output window (try holding Ctrl and clicking on the filename in an error message).